# RxJava Observable.cache invalidate

Tags: android, rx-java

I am trying to learn rxjava inside Android environment.
Let's say I have an observable that emits the result of a network call.
If I understood correctly, a widely common approach to deal with config changes is to:

- store the observable in a retained fragment / singleton / application object
- apply the **cache** operator to the observable
- subscribe / unsubscribe in the proper lifecycle handlers

Doing this, we would not loose the result of the observable which will re-observerd once the new configuration took place.

Now, my question is:

Is there a way to force the observable to emit a new value (and invalidate the cached one)? Do I need to create a new observable every time I want fresh data from the network (which does not sound like a bad practice in android world because would make the gc do extra work)?

Thanks a lot,

Federico

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Make a custom `OnSubscribe` implementation that does what you want:

```
public static class OnSubscribeRefreshingCache<T> implements OnSubscribe<T> {

    private final AtomicBoolean refresh = new AtomicBoolean(true);
    private final Observable<T> source;
    private volatile Observable<T> current;

    public OnSubscribeRefreshingCache(Observable<T> source) {
        this.source = source;
        this.current = source;
    }

    public void reset() {
        refresh.set(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void call(Subscriber<? super T> subscriber) {
        if (refresh.compareAndSet(true, false)) {
            current = source.cache();
        }
        current.unsafeSubscribe(subscriber);
    }

}
```

This bit of code demonstrates usage and shows that cache is essentially being reset:

```
Observable<Integer> o = Observable.just(1)
        .doOnCompleted(() -> System.out.println("completed"));
OnSubscribeRefreshingCache<Integer> cacher = 
    new OnSubscribeRefreshingCache<Integer>(o);
Observable<Integer> o2 = Observable.create(cacher);
o2.subscribe(System.out::println);
o2.subscribe(System.out::println);
cacher.reset();
o2.subscribe(System.out::println);
```

Output:

```
completed
1
1
completed
1
```

By the way you may notice that `.cache` doesn't emit till completion. This is a bug that should be fixed by rxjava 1.0.14.

In terms of your GC pressure concerns, every operator when applied to an Observable creates a new Observable usually via `lift` or `create`. The base member state associated with creating a new Observable is the reference to the `onSubscribe` function. `cache` is different from most in that it holds state across subscriptions and this holds potential for GC pressure if it holds a lot of state and is thrown away frequently. Even if you used the same mutable data structure to hold the state across resets GC would still have to deal with the contents of the data structure when cleared so you might not gain much.

The RxJava `cache` operator is built for multiple concurrent subscriptions. You can probably imagine a reset functionality could prove problematic to implement. By all means raise an issue on RxJava github if you want to explore further.

Comment: cleaned up a little bit

Comment: Looks neat! However, by doing that we have a more elegant and rx-ish api but I think we are just hiding the observable recreation. If I did not read rxjava's source wrong, .cache() returns a new (cached) observable: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/blob/230bdca4b674f7d8c6ce13b47d33fe9598ad89bb/src/main/java/rx/internal/operators/CachedObservable.java#L56

Comment: Thanks again for your answer, could not have been more accurate :-)