# RxJava and Android: how to invalidate observable that use cache()?

Tags: android, caching, rx-java, retrofit2, rx-android

I have an Activity that loads data using RxJava and Retrofit2. To prevent the request from being triggered every time a configuration change occurs, I use the `cache()` operator. This works well and I can see that the request is made only once. The problem is that from time to time, I need to make a new request to get fresh data. In another words, I need to invalidate the cache. How can I do that?

The activity is using a repository to make the request:

```
public class Repository {
private final PlaceholderApi api;
private Observable<List<Post>> obs;
private static Repository inst;

public static Repository instance() {
    if (inst == null) {
        inst = new Repository();
    }
    return inst;
}

private Repository() {
    HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor(message -> System.out.println(message));
    logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BASIC);
    OkHttpClient okhttp = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addInterceptor(logging)
            .build();
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .client(okhttp)
            .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create())
            .baseUrl("http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/")
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.createWithScheduler(Schedulers.io()))
            .build();
    api = retrofit.create(PlaceholderApi.class);
}

public Observable<List<Post>> getAll() {
    if (obs == null) {
        obs = api.getPosts().cache();
    }
    return obs;
}
}
```

And the activity code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
private Subscription sub1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    sub1 = Repository.instance().getAll().subscribe(/* handle posts list */);
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (sub1 != null && !sub1.isUnsubscribed()) {
        sub1.unsubscribe();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31733455/rxjava-observable-cache-invalidate

Comment: @DaveMoten, thanks for the link but how to do that with Retrofit?

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example using the OnSubscribeRefreshingCache wrapper class from Dave Moten's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31738646/6491552) with your code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
private Subscription sub1;
private OnSubscribeRefreshingCache<List<Post>> postCache;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        postCache = new OnSubscribeRefreshingCache(Repository.instance().getAll());
        sub1 = subscribe(Observable.create(postCache));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (sub1 != null && !sub1.isUnsubscribed()) {
            sub1.unsubscribe();
        }
    }

    private Subscription subscribe(Observable<List<Post> postObservable){
        return postObservable.subscribe(/* handle posts list */);
    }

    private void invalidateCache(){
        postCache.reset();
        sub1 = subscribe(Observable.create(postCache));
    }
}
```

Then call the `invalidateCache()` method during one of the Activity lifecycle methods or whatever works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to solve your problem, is using [OperatorFreeze](https://github.com/MaksTuev/ferro) (without operator cache), if you use persistent presenter. This operator can pause your Observable when configuration change occurs and resume it when activity recreated. You also don't need to store Observables in repository.